# ValueError with unpacking in python

Tags: python

For the code below, I always get the error `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`. it is reading from a `txt file` with 5 different lines of content so definitely it has more than 1 line.

```
 with open("People.txt", 'r') as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
       ip,user,password = line.strip().split(',')
```

The text file looks like this:

```
 ip,username,password
```

Comment: you're probably splitting more than 3 values, what python version is this?

Comment: Are there any blank lines in the file? What happens if you `print line.strip().split(',')`?

Comment: Suggest you test to see what line.strip().split(',') actually returned

Comment: When i print them i get 5 lines of data and a blank line

Comment: Then the blank line is the problem. You should add a check for blank lines.

Comment: That got it, Man thats stupid

Comment: What is your Python version? I am running your code with `Python 2.7.7` and I don't get any error!

Comment: Yes, because you have not inserted a newline at the end of your test data... may look for my answer, it ignores unfitting data.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @parchment in the comments located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362319/valueerror-with-unpacking-in-python#comment41382578_26362319).

> Then the blank line is the problem. You should add a check for blank
>   lines. –  parchment

Sample useful recipe:

```
In [17]: with open("src.txt") as f:
    ...:     for f_ in f:
    ...:         if f_.strip(): # One quick way to check for blank lines.
    ...:             one_,two_ = f_.strip().split(",")
    ...:             print one_, two_
foo bar
spam grok

In [18]:
```

Comment: I think mine is more robust. Because we are split for commas and unpack at least three values. In your case unpacking will fail if input data don't satisfy.

Comment: It's not about whether the above doesn't satisfy the input. The key here is the usage of `f.strip()` to identify blank lines. Whatever the eventual form of the input is or how user deals with it is part of his approach, which is not detailed in the OP anyway. There's no clear information that it's any less than 2 commas per line, nor are there possibilities of more. Also, note that this was posted as a community wiki. It's not for points *anyway*.

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't see the wiki entry too.

Answer (score -3):

May you have a newline at the end of the file. You could do it more robust for example like that.

```
with open("People.txt", 'r') as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        if line.count(',') == 2:
            ip,user,password = line.strip().split(',')
```